# Polymorphic deserialization with object root

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

What's the best way do deserialize the following YAML file

```
widgets:
  square:
    color: red
  circle:
    color: blue
```

into this class hierarchy?

```
public abstract class Widget {
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Square : Widget { }

public class Circle : Widget { }

public class WidgetList {
    public IEnumerable<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @dymanoid Nothing so far. It seems that custom `INodeDeserializer` is needed but I haven't dug into yet thinking someone has already done that

Comment: It looks like this can be done implementing `IYamlTypeConverter`. Unfortunately, this appears to require manually coding the  serialization/deserialization logic for everything - as far as I can tell we cannot use any of the YamlDotNet serialization/deserialization logic when we do this. Which is really not much help at all... sorry

Comment: I'm new to YamlDotNet, but I think you need a custom naming convention to drop the `s` (convert from plural widgets to WidgetList).